# Remove part of string from Sublime Text 3 output console, Lua

Tags: lua, console, output, sublimetext

[image]

Is there a way to remove string "[Finished in ...s]" from output every time I build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build system has the `quiet` attribute to do exactly that. Just open the lua build system, e.g. via [PackageResourceViewer](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer), add `"quiet": true,` and save the file. It should look like this:

```js
{
    "cmd": ["lua", "$file"],
    "quiet": true,
    "file_regex": "^(?:lua:)?[\t ](...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.lua"
}
```